# Pythonにて「色の代表」ピクセルを選択するアルゴリズムを知りたいです

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, scipy

RGB形式の画像があります。
この画像は高さ900、横900ピクセルとします。
画像には80色あります。900＊900=810000ピクセルの画像ですので、80色しかありませんので、1個以上のピクセルが同じ色です。
このように複数のピクセルが同じ色の場合にその色の「代表ピクセル」を選びたいです。但し、選ばれた「代表ピクセル」とその周りの変色度はその他の同じ色のピクセルとその周りの変色度より低く（最も低い）なければなりません。例えば、赤のピクセル[255,0,0]を選ぶ場合には周りの８ピクセルがオール[255,0,0]の物と周りが白「255,255,255]がありましたら、周りとの変色度が比較的低い周りが赤の物を選びます。この場合の変色度は[255,0,0] - [255,0,0] = [0,0,0]ですのでゼロです。`np.sum(np.abs(diff))`的に変色度を計算して問題ありません。
その次の条件として、80色ありますが、選ばれた80個がなるべく画像内で散らばっているように選びたいです。一箇所、何箇所かに固まっていないようにしたいです。

Comment: 何がしたいのか（何が出来れば満足なのか）がいまいち判らないのですが、上手くいくかどうかは元の画像のデータ次第じゃないですかね。

Comment: @mLstudent33 「存在する場合」というのは、何が存在する場合の話をしていますか？

Comment: その色のピクセルがある場合。例として真っ白な画像には黒いピクセルは存在しないが、白いピクセルは多く存在する。

Comment: それは「存在する」の説明であって、主語（「その色」）の説明ではないですよね。主語が曖昧になっていて意味が上手くとれなかったので説明して欲しい、という意図でした。「一箇所にしかない数値のピクセル」「何箇所にもあるピクセル」のどちらを指していますか？

Comment: 「散らばっている」を判定する指標は何ですか？　画像の淵にあるピクセルに隣接するピクセルは８個未満だが、変色度の算出方法はどうしますか？

Comment: `np.abs(pixel_1_val - pixel_b_val) + np.abs(pixe1_val - pixel_c_val) + ...+ np.abs(pixel_a_val - pixel_n_val)` ピクセルn個の場合。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> np.sum(np.abs(diff))的に変色度を計算して問題ありません

あるピクセルと周囲のピクセル(`surr`)の RGB 値の差分(絶対値)の総計を計算しています。実際には画像の端(edge)や角(corner)にあるピクセルの場合、周囲にあるピクセル数が 3 や 5 になるので、差分の総計値をそのピクセル数で割っています。

以下のコードでは [Pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/) ライブラリを利用しています。

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

im = Image.open('test.png').convert('RGB')
w, h = im.size
surr = [
  (-1, -1), (0, -1), (1, -1),
  (-1,  0),          (1,  0),
  (-1,  1), (0,  1), (1,  1),
]

pixel = np.reshape(np.array(im.getdata()), (h, w, 3))
typical = {}
for y in range(h):
  for x in range(w):
    (r0, g0, b0) = pixel[y, x]
    p_surr = [
      pixel[y+dy, x+dx] for (dx, dy) in surr
      if 0 <= x+dx < w and 0 <= y+dy < h
    ]
    d = sum(
      [abs(r-r0) + abs(g-g0) + abs(b-b0) for (r, g, b) in p_surr]
    ) / len(p_surr)

    if (r0, g0, b0) not in typical or d < typical[(r0, g0, b0)][0]:
      typical[(r0, g0, b0)] = (d, x, y)

im = Image.new('RGB', (w, h), (0, 0, 0, 255))
for k, (_, x, y) in typical.items():
  print("({:3}, {:3}, {:3}): ({:3}, {:3})".format(k[0], k[1], k[2], x, y))
  im.putpixel((x, y), k) 
im.save('typical_pixels.png')
```

以下、左は適当に作成した80色の画像(サイズは300x300)で、右は処理結果です(`typical_pixels.png`)。

[image: 元画像] [image: typical pixels]

> その次の条件として、80色ありますが、選ばれた80個がなるべく画像内で散らばっているように選びたいです。一箇所、何箇所かに固まっていないようにしたいです。

「散らばっている」とか「一箇所、何箇所かに固まっていない」などという表現だけでは判断ができませんので、何らかの数量的な指標が必要です。

Comment: ピクセル間の総計euclidean distanceをMaximize的な条件で大丈夫ですか。上記のご回答ありがとうございます。とても参考になります。大学の授業でPILは推薦されていませんしたので使っていませんが、便利ですね。勉強になりました。

Comment: `d = sum([abs(r-r0) + ...` の部分は適当に思い付いた計算式ですので、適宜変更して見て下さい。